# Is it a good practice to have last_update field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timestamp

I runned MySQL Workbench today and it has `Sakila Model`. In each table there is a `last_update` field. My question is: Is it a good practice to have last_update field in MySQL or no? When we should use this field and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Something like last_update is good to have and can be triggered when you do your UPDATE SQL by something as simple as adding this to your queries.  Just something where you have last_update as a timestamp and you use NOW put the current timestamp.

```
last_update=NOW()
```

You can usually code without these but if down the road you want to get stats on updates and other data, if you never save it, you will not have it.